# Function to handle optional chunksize in pandas read_sql()

Tags: python, sql, pandas, teradata

I'm building a function for users to easily input SQL queries / script and obtain the results in a pandas dataframe, as part of a wider set of simplified tools for end users at my workplace.

The issue I'm now having is I need to implement the `pd.read_sql()` [chunksize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) argument, which changes the output of `pd.read_sql()` from a `pd.DataFrame` to an `iterator object`.

So the key snippet, before implementing `chunksize` was:

```
 outputs = {}  # Dict to store the dataframe outputs
 counter = 0

    for command in tqdm(commands):
        try:
            # If SELECT statement, read into dict of dataframes
            if command.upper().strip()[:3] == "SEL":

                outputs[counter] = pd.read_sql(command, con):
                counter += 1
```

Whereas to handle the case when the `chunksize` argument is optionally selected, I would handle it with:

```
outputs = {}
counter = 0

    for command in tqdm(commands):
        try:
            if command.upper().strip()[:3] == "SEL":

                for chunk in pd.read_sql(command, con, chunksize=chunksize):
                    outputs[counter] = chunk
                    counter += 1
```

I'm looking to see if there's a clean way to dynamically handle the user selecting, or not selecting, the `chunksize` argument. I could of course use an `if/else` statement, but I've been getting very close to pylint errors of `too many branches / nests` (aka making arrow code) and I feel like there should be a way to dynamically handle this. Would really appreciate advice on cleanest / most efficient approach.

One solution I did think of was setting chunksize = 1 + chunksize_selected_by_user, but I don't really know what the efficiency implications of always using chunksize is, when not strictly necessary.

Comment: What about passing `chunksize` into your function as an argument, which defaults to 1000 (for example) and can be overridden by the user if needed.  `def get_stuff(chunksize=1000): ...`

Comment: I like this idea but my concern is does *always* using chunksize slow things down if its not necessary?

Comment: [These notes](https://acepor.github.io/2017/08/03/using-chunksize/) might help to answer your question.  General rule of thumb (in personal experience) is to use large chunks providing it's not too large to cause a memory conflict.